# Best fit circles inside a square based on side of the square

Tags: geometry

Hi,

How to calculate number of circles in side a square, if we know the side of the square and the circles all are equal size.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is "probably yes", but (a) who wants to know? and (b) I am fairly sure that the subject is NOT complex geometry. Voting to close.

Comment: if yes, how can we calculate number of circles inside a square?

Comment: This is a website for questions of interest to research mathematicians - please see the faq. You might try math.stackexchange for your question, although you will also need to work a bit on the phrasing of the question so as to make it less ambiguous. 

Comment: Posted now at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94941/

Answer (score 5):

The right question is: given a positive integer $n$, what is the largest $r$ such that $n$ non-overlapping circles of radius $r$ can fit inside a unit square?  It's not simply a matter of hexagonal close-packing, because boundary effects are important.  There is no known closed-form formula, and not likely to be one, but the values are known for $n$ up to 30.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square and
http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/csq.html

Answer (score 0):

Given a square of side $L$, the area covered by circles, including partial circles, will be $\frac{\pi L^2}{\sqrt{12}}$; since the [optimal circle packing density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing#Packings_in_the_plane) in the plane is $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{12}}$.

Therefore, given circles of radius $r$, the number of circles which fit in the square should be the greatest integer less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\frac{L^2}{r^2}$

Comment: As @Robert Israel points out, boundary effects are important, so your second statement is almost certainly false.